# Want to disable search history from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, search

When i search  a word in search box it gives related search from complte website and also shows the serch history overlaps search suggestions .
I have lots of googled but don't know how to shortout this problem.
Suggest plzz.
Thanks,Monika

Comment: Why not post your question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/? You might be able to find help more quickly.

Comment: Could you at least give us a link or something so we can see what's going on?

Comment: http://worklab.in/wordpress/farsiban2/ check it

Answer (score 2):

All WordPress sites set `name='s'` for their search forms, so your browser will make suggestions based on queries you've entered on other WordPress sites.

You can disable it by setting `autocomplete='off'`.

For example:
`<input type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Thanku @Chris Fletcher it works for me.